# Как получить все *.mp3 ?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, javascript, perl

Не получается из html файла вытянуть все адреса музыкальных файлов.
Мне надо вытянуть все вхождения  соответствующие вот такому регулярному выражению
http.*mp3 но как, я не знаю.
хотелось бы реализовать на php perl javascript
Извините за нубский вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно получить список всех ссылок на mp3 файлы с помощью простого css-селектора — `a[href$=mp3]`. Получается, для того, чтобы получить список ссылок на странице нужно просто выполнить в консоли разработчика такую команду:

```
// Если есть jQuery
$('a[href$=mp3]')

// Если jQuery нет, но браузер не очень старый
document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=mp3]');
```

Comment: только я бы написал так

    $('a[href$=mp3]')

а то оно даже на этой странице (этой странице хешкода, на которой прям сейчас находимся), найдет ссылку с mp3.

Comment: То есть `$('a[href$=".mp3"]')`?

Comment: да, почему то у меня вылетеле точка.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно конечно посмотреть, какой там файл внутри. Но вот набросок на перл

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $content = get("http://www.site.not/");
while ($content =~ /(http.*?\.mp3)/gi) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

конечно, лучше применить парсер html и сделать красиво.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url("http://www.site.not/");

foreach my $b ($root->find_by_tag_name('a')) {
    my $url $b->attr('href');
    if ($url =~ /.mp3$/) {
      print "$url\n";
    }
}
```